# How can I add insulation above my finished ceiling?

Tags: insulation, ceiling, roof

What is the cheapest option for adding insulation above a finished ceiling? There has never been any in the spot that I need it. Should I take the roof off or have it sprayed in? The space is 20 feet long and 9 feet 9 inches wide.

Comment: Please add more details so we can better answer your question. Do you not have attic access to add more insulation?

Comment: It is somewhat unlikely that taking off the roof will be the least expensive option.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on construction details. if it's merely "the contractor was too cheap to provide attic access" (a very typical issue of cheesy contractors), you cut a hole and put in access, then apply insulation as you like. If it's a cathedral ceiling sort of arrangement (roof deck on one side of rafters, ceiling on the other) then some sort of spray/blown insulation (might be foam, might be cellulose, might be fiberglass but I would not go there based on published research results) is the most likely option, though not the only option. If you are considering "taking off the roof" then it's usually more cost-effective (labor cost, mostly) to leave it in place & build on top of the current roof with a layer of insulation, for instance.

Comment: this room was a garages an I made it into a family room  its a two story house  an this is the part that's on first floor with just the roof I also put a fireplace in though that roof an there's no insolation in it  I loss all my heat so I wanted to put insolation in I do need a roof in the next few years so I think I will just take the roof off an sheeting an do it that way in stand of blowing it in  I just wanted to know if that was the cheeps way .....

Comment: The "cheapest way to insulate" is essentially never "taking the roof off." Blown-in cellulose will be far more cost effective in the current space.